# How can I create image overlay over an image hover effect in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, css-transitions

I want to create similar effect as shown on the gif below. It should support image and image overlay of **different dimensions**.

[image: image hover effect]

I have successfully created beforementioned effect, however the image overlay did not cover the container when it had different dimension from the image.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cozytux.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/placehold.it-500x750.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/03/8b/b8/038bb804bd1611a46e4b1bafc4c6bca3.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.kingsporttn.gov/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/500x500.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="https://driverslicenserestorers.com/wp-content/uploads/placeholder-500x500.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share what you have done already?

Comment: @OtmanBouchari I have edited  my post to link the code.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the two images have different aspect-ratios?

Comment: The two images should cover the container with defined width and height.

Comment: Hi @andrej-vranec, can you share any such e-commerce website URL where this type of image hover effect is visible? because as per my knowledge you need same dimension images to achieve this effect shown in GIF image. You need to consider some presets for image sizes. I checked flipkart and they are using fixed size container with image changing inside

Comment: @JigneshRaval  I have seen the effect on https://www.ikea.com/. They are also using the same dimensions for images. It seems it is my only option to resize them.

Comment: Hi @andrej-vranec, you can check similar implementation here : https://www.ikea.com/in/en/cat/sofas-armchairs-fu003/ - but still it requires either same image dimensions or fixed container dimensions with variable image size in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both image have the same size, and the size known, you may use a single img tag and the box-sizing propertie. This option will aloow you to use both image in your tag. The one to show at first in the src attribute and the other one as a background.
Below a snippet to show the idea, hover the image

```css
img {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:500px;
  height:280px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/30/500/280);
  transition:0.25s
}
img:hover {
  padding:140px 250px;/* all paddings equals the size of the image itself */
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
```

You can even add a transition and play with the padding value to decide from which side to hide/show the other image.

here is a few more examples:

```css
img {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:500px;
  height:280px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/30/500/280);
  transition:0.25s
}
img:hover {
  padding:140px 250px;
}
img:nth-child(2):hover {
  padding:140px 0;
}
img:nth-child(3):hover {
  padding:0 250px ;
 }
img:nth-child(4):hover {
  padding:0 500px 0 0;
 }
img:nth-child(5):hover {
  padding:0 0 0 500px;
 }
img:nth-child(6):hover {
  padding: 280px 0 0;
 }
img:nth-child(7):hover {
  padding:0 0 280px 0;
 } 
img:nth-child(8):hover {
  padding: 280px 500px 0 0;
 }
img:nth-child(9):hover {
  padding: 0 0 280px 500px;
 }

img:nth-child(10):hover {
  padding:0  500px  280px 0;
 }
img:nth-child(11):hover {
  padding:  280px 0 0  500px;
 }
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280">
```

Here is an example using CSS var() in case that each duo of image are of different sizes. Css var() will avoid to rewrite a rule for each case:
example below:

```css
img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/30/500/280);
  transition: 0.25s
}

img:hover {
  padding: calc(var(--height) / 2) calc(var(--width) / 2);
}


/* below other possible slide out */




/* each of these rule are for a different effect , not because of different sizes */
img:nth-child(2):hover {
  padding: calc(var(--height) / 2) 0;
}

img:nth-child(3):hover {
  padding: 0 calc(var(--width) / 2);
}

img:nth-child(4):hover {
  padding: 0 var(--width) 0 0;
}

img:nth-child(5):hover {
  padding: 0 0 0 var(--width);
}

img:nth-child(6):hover {
  padding: var(--height) 0 0;
}

img:nth-child(7):hover {
  padding: 0 0 var(--height) 0;
}

img:nth-child(8):hover {
  padding: var(--height) var(--width) 0 0;
}

img:nth-child(9):hover {
  padding: 0 0 var(--height) var(--width);
}

img:nth-child(10):hover {
  padding: 0 var(--width) var(--height) 0;
}

img:nth-child(11):hover {
  padding: var(--height) 0 0 var(--width);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280" style="--width:500px;--height:280px">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/400/280" style="--width:400px;--height:280px">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/200/180" style="--width:200px;--height:180px">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/180" style="--width:500px;--height:180px">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/50/80" style="--width:50px;--height:80px">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/300/300" style="--width:300px;--height:300px">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280" style="--width:500px;--height:280px">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/450/320" style="--width:450px;--height:320px">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/200/200" style="--width:200px;--height:200px">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/300/300" style="--width:300px;--height:300px">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/200/100" style="--width:200px;--height:100px">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/500/280" style="--width:500px;--height:280px">
```

**NOTE** if both images are of different sizes or ratio, you have background-size and object-fit to resize or clamp them. Give us some examples of pairs of different sizes/ratio to show you some ways/ideas.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Do you think it would be possible to edit the code in such a way it could support images of different sizes?

Comment: @andrejvranec Javascript can help on the fly to resset CSS values. A possibility is also at the moment of inserting your HTML tag inside your code to add css var() that can be used from the rule. I'll put a third example.

Comment: There is also object-fit/background-size that could used if pairs are of different sizes or ratio or if you need the image always the same size.

Comment: I have created example on https://codepen.io/andrej-vranec/pen/NWeYweP of images of different sizes and it seems it works :). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
.container img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

You need to fit the image. I'll recommend to have same size for both images.

Comment: The question specified that the images might be of different dimensions.